# nodemon is crashing after several changes done in project files?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, nodemon

When I update the project Files I get this issue given Below:

```
events.js:183
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^

 Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::4000
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
at Function.listen (E:\nodejs-mysql-authentication- master\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\nodejs-mysql-authentication-master\server.js:26:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I already try all this point to short out this issue given below

1.I manually stops the all node services than again I try npm start It's not worked if i change port 4001 it's work after, some time again same issue port 4001.

2.I Increase the nodemon file watcher size but still this issue not get solved.

But When I restart My PC again then nodemon is working on same port.
So How I can solve this issue, If  I don't want to change my port and can't restart my PC.

Comment: Can you try following steps for me? 1. Start using nodemon on 4000 port. 2. check using `netstat -lpn`. 3. Let it restart and check again with `netstat -lpn`.

Comment: EADDRINUSE = Address/Port in use. Basically, it's restarting but not killing the other process or its children.

Comment: Nope It's not worked. I already did this previously. @Jack

Comment: In what files you are making change.

Comment: Did you try 1. removing nodemon  `npm unistall nodemon -g` 2. `npm cache clean` 3. reinstalling again `npm i nodemon -g`

Comment: Any file related to project like Routes folder files , utils folder files. This issue I never face when I changes any files. But from last week this issue is arise.

Comment: Okay try my above comment and let me know if it works now.

Comment: Nope >npm uninstall nodemon -g and reinstall is not working. In my all three PC I am facing same Issue.I updated the node and nodemon also previously but Issue is not gone.

Comment: What is the version of nodemon? this is fixed in nodemon@1.12.6!

Comment: Nodemon version 1.18.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176995/discussion-between-prashant-gupta-and-jack).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `--signal SIGTERM` to nodemon command line fixed for me. You can have more details at [nodemon project @ github.com](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/760)

The issue occurs due to a thread still running when nodemon restarts the app, and this thread is already using the port you want to use. You can confirm this with these steps:

- Make nodemon crash. You should see something like the error posted by OP
- hit `CTRL+c` when it happens to stop nodemon
- enter `netstat -napt | grep [YOUR_PORT]`, replace [YOUR_PORT] with the port number you are using. In the OP's case it's 4000
- you should get the process listening on that port. The command will return something like this:

  ```
  ff@darkpc:~/dev/dp/graphql/teste1> netstat -napt | grep 4000
  (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
  tcp6    0      0 :::4000           :::*                    LISTEN      31837/node8
  ```
- if you try to run nodemon again it will crash!
- kill the process using your port with `kill 31837` in this case `31387` is the PID of node8 as you can see above
- run nodemon again and it will work.

Adding the `--signal SIGTERM` to nodemon command line will kill the main process and all it's threads and should fix the problem.

Comment: I searched everywhere for a solution to this very annoying issue and this is what finally did it, thank you! Note, you can also put the setting in a `nodemon.json` in your project root, e.g. `{ "signal": "SIGTERM" }`